# as3 StageText cursor does not show up

Tags: android, actionscript-3, mobile, air, adobe

here is the code that creates the StageText

```
var myTextField:StageText = new StageText();
myTextField.returnKeyLabel = ReturnKeyLabel.SEARCH;
myTextField.text = tlf.text;
myTextField.editable = true;
myTextField.fontFamily = "Ariel"
myTextField.fontSize = 40;
myTextField.color =  tlf.textColor
myTextField.textAlign = TextFormatAlign.RIGHT
myTextField.stage = stage;
myTextField.viewPort = new Rectangle(p.x,  p.y, tlf.width*screenUtil.xScaleFactor,tlf.height*screenUtil.yScaleFactor);
txtInputVo.stageText = myTextField;
myTextField.locale = "he-IL";
myTextField.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onInFocus);
myTextField.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, onOutFocus);
protected function onInFocus(event:FocusEvent):void
{
    var sTxt:StageText = event.currentTarget as StageText;
    var textInputVo:TextInputVO =  getTextInputVO(sTxt);
    if(textInputVo.defultText == sTxt.text)
    {
        sTxt.text = "";
    }
}
```

It's working great, the keybord is showing up and you can insert and edit the text 
but the cursor is not showing up?

I have only tested it on the Android Air 3.6 so far.

Comment: I noticed your code is listening for an event to fire but I don't see where you add an event listener to any objects? For example, myTextField.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onInFocus);

Comment: I have it the original code I will add it on the snapping thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the `assignFocus()` function of the `StageText` object to see if the cursor appears? For example try adding a function for debug purposes that assigns focus to `myTextField`. ie. `myTextField.assignFocus();` Also I believe this line of code `if(textInputVo.defultText == sTxt.text)` should read `if(textInputVo.defaultText == sTxt.text)`

Comment: Anther issue with the StageText and RTL  
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3537430

Answer (score 1):

Try "Arial" not "Ariel" as font family